# QThread doesn't exit

Tags: multithreading, qt

Here is a piece of code:

```
class ServerThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ServerThread();
    void executeCommand(const char *command);
private:
    Server server;
};

void Server::executeCommand(const char *command) {
    QString qCommand = command;
    if (qCommand == "close") {
        closeServer();
        emit serverClosed();
    } else if (true) {

    }
}

ServerThread::ServerThread() {
    connect(&server, SIGNAL(serverClosed()), this, SLOT(quit()));
}

void ServerThread::executeCommand(const char *command) {
    server.executeCommand(command);
}
```

The signal serverClosed() is emmited but ServerThread doesn't seem to quit(). Why?

Comment: I assume, since you say the ServerThread doesn't `quit()`, that you are calling `start()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I've read that it happens because of 
    server.start();
    std::string command;
    do {
        std::getline(std::cin, command);
        server.executeCommand(command.c_str());
    } while (true);
but how can I create an input loop without locking the main thread?

Comment: Also: is your intention that executeCommand run in the ServerThread's thread?  If you just make it an ordinary member function like that, it will run in the caller's thread...you'd need it to be in a slot.

Comment: There's no start(), no wait(), no moveToThread(), no run().  We need to see a more complete example.

Comment: Yes, this is not enough code to tell you.  But another diagnostic angle: if you make some other custom slot and emit a signal that triggers it, is that slot getting a chance to run?  (If not, then you may be tying up the thread without ever returning control to the event loop, so the `quit()` is just pending in the event queue.)

Answer (score 0):

Read to following article to understand the workings of QThread: [Threads, Events and QObjects](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects). As Colin has commented you will need at least start() and moveToThread().

Comment: moveToThread is "wrong"... http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/